# JavaFX RemoteException on ListView?

Tags: java, listview, exception, javafx, remoteexception

I have a JFXListView of JFXButtons. The code used to work correctly. I don't know what happened, but I am get the following exception when click a JFXButton of that JFXListView :

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.2; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:393)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.paramService(Unknown Source)
        at javafxcyberwind.UtilisateurController.lambda$getServices$13(UtilisateurController.java:164)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.2; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:112)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at javafxcyberwind.Cloud_ServeurIMPL.paramService(Cloud_ServeurIMPL.java:244)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 23 more
```

Thats the controller where the exception occured :

```
package javafxcyberwind;

import static javafxcyberwind.LoginController.R;

public class UtilisateurController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

    ScreensController myController;

    @FXML
    private JFXListView li_se;

    @FXML
    private StackPane st_dl;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pn_us, pn_li;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle rec;

    ServerSocket sv;
    private int p1, k;
    IP ip = new IP();
    File selectedFile;
    boolean t = false;
    private final String urep = "c:/Utilisateur/";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        File p = new File(urep);
        p.mkdir();
        String[] entries = p.list();
        for (String s : entries) {
            File currentFile = new File(p.getPath(), s);
            currentFile.delete();
        }
        li_se.getItems().clear();   
    }

    @FXML
    public void getServices(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            li_se.getItems().clear();
            for (Object service : R.ListeService()) {
                JFXButton b = new JFXButton("" + service);
                b.setStyle("-fx-rippler-fill:black;-fx-text-fill:black;-fx-font-size:16px;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                b.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                    try {
                        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
                        JFXListView li_par = new JFXListView();
                        JFXTextField[] fields = new JFXTextField[22];
                        TextFieldEntier[] fEntiers = new TextFieldEntier[22];
                        TextFieldReel[] fRéels = new TextFieldReel[22];
                        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
                        choiceBox.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/choise-box.css").toExternalForm());
                        choiceBox.getItems().addAll("true", "false");
                        ArrayList<Object> tab = new ArrayList<>();
                        JFXButton folder = new JFXButton("Ouvrir le répertoire");
                        folder.setDisable(true);
                        ObservableList<String> ListParam = FXCollections.observableArrayList(R.paramService(b.getText()));
                        JFXDialogLayout content = new JFXDialogLayout();
                        content.setHeading(new Text(b.getText()));
                        content.setBody(vBox);
                        JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(st_dl, content, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
                        k = 0;
                        ListParam.stream().map((st) -> {
                            if (st.equals("double")) {
                                fRéels[k] = new TextFieldReel();
                                fRéels[k].setPadding(new Insets(11));
                                Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Réel ) : ");
                                lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                                lb.setStyle("-fx-min-Width:178;-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                                HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                                hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                                hb.getChildren().add(fRéels[k]);
                                li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                            }
                            return st;
                        }).map((st) -> {
                            if (st.equals("java.lang.String")) {
                                fields[k] = new JFXTextField();
                                fields[k].setMinHeight(35);
                                fields[k].setMinWidth(157);
                                Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Texte ) : ");
                                lb.setMinWidth(178);
                                lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                                lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                                HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                                hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                                hb.getChildren().add(fRéels[k]);
                                li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                            }
                            return st;
                        }).map((st) -> {
                            if (st.equals("int")) {
                                fEntiers[k] = new TextFieldEntier();
                                fEntiers[k].setPadding(new Insets(11));
                                Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Entier ) : ");
                                lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                                lb.setStyle("-fx-min-Width:178;-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                                HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                                hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                                hb.getChildren().add(fEntiers[k]);
                                li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                            }
                            return st;
                        }).map((st) -> {
                            if (st.equals("boolean")) {
                                Label lb = new Label("Argument ( " + st + " ) : ");
                                lb.setMinWidth(178);
                                lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                                lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                                HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                                hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                                hb.getChildren().add(choiceBox);
                                li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                            }
                            return st;
                        }).map((st) -> {
                            if (st.equals("java.io.File")) {
                                fields[k] = new JFXTextField();
                                fields[k].setMinHeight(35);
                                fields[k].setMinWidth(157);
                                Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Fichier ) : ");
                                lb.setMinWidth(178);
                                lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                                lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                                HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                                hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                                hb.getChildren().add(fields[k]);
                                li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                                int x = k;
                                fields[k].addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent e1) -> {
                                    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
                                    selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                                    if (selectedFile != null) {
                                        fields[x].setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            return st;
                        }).forEachOrdered((_item) -> {
                            k++;
                        });
                        JFXButton exe = new JFXButton("Exécuter");
                        WeatherIconView weatherIcon = new WeatherIconView(WeatherIcon.CLOUD);
                        weatherIcon.setSize("30");
                        weatherIcon.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
                        exe.setGraphic(weatherIcon);
                        exe.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:DODGERBLUE;-fx-background-color:white;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                        exe.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                        JFXTextField res = new JFXTextField();
                        res.setMinWidth(150);
                        Label re = new Label("Résultat");
                        HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                        hb.getChildren().add(re);
                        hb.getChildren().add(res);
                        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                        hb.getChildren().add(folder);
                        li_par.setMaxHeight(180);
                        li_par.setMinWidth(384);
                        vBox.getChildren().add(li_par);
                        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                        vBox.getChildren().add(exe);
                        vBox.getChildren().add(hb);
                        exe.setOnAction((ActionEvent e2) -> {
                            tab.clear();
                            try {
                                int k1 = 0;
                                for (String st : ListParam) {
                                    if (st.equals("int")) {
                                        tab.add(Integer.valueOf(fEntiers[k1].getText()));
                                    }
                                    if (st.equals("double")) {
                                        tab.add(Double.valueOf(fRéels[k1].getText()));
                                    }
                                    if (st.equals("boolean")) {
                                        tab.add(Boolean.valueOf(choiceBox.getValue()));
                                    }
                                    if (st.equals("java.lang.String")) {
                                        tab.add(fields[k1].getText());
                                    }
                                    if (st.equals("java.io.File")) {
                                        Fichier f = new Fichier(selectedFile.getName());
                                        tab.add(f);
                                        p1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (9000 - 5000)) + 5000);
                                        R.uploadToCloud(p1, selectedFile.getName());
                                        Socket s = new Socket(ip.IPserveur(), p1);
                                        ObjectOutputStream out;
                                        FileInputStream inf = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                                        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                                        int n;
                                        while ((n = inf.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                            out.write(buf, 0, n);
                                        }
                                        out.close();
                                    }
                                    k1++;
                                }
                                if (R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("int") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("double") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("boolean") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("class java.lang.String")) {
                                    R.envoieDemande(b.getText(), "", 0, tab.toArray());
                                    res.setText("" + R.getResult());
                                }
                                if (R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("class java.io.File")) {
                                    p1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (9000 - 5000)) + 5000);
                                    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(p1);
                                    Utilisateur_MethodsPAIRIMPL U = new Utilisateur_MethodsPAIRIMPL();
                                    Naming.bind("rmi://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + p1 + "/" + R.getEmail(), U);
                                    R.envoieDemande(b.getText(), InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), p1, tab.toArray());
                                    res.setText(urep + R.getResfile());
                                    folder.setDisable(false);
                                }
                            } catch (RemoteException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                                alert.setTitle("Erreur");
                                alert.setHeaderText("Erreur");
                                alert.setContentText("Veuillez choisir une option");
                                ButtonType btn_annuler = new ButtonType("Annuler");
                                ButtonType btn_réessayer = new ButtonType("Réessayer");
                                alert.setGraphic(new ImageView("icon/erreur.png"));
                                alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(btn_réessayer, btn_annuler);
                                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                                ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                                TextArea area = new TextArea(sw.toString());
                                alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(area);
                                Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
                                stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon/erreur.png"));
                                Optional<ButtonType> res1 = alert.showAndWait();
                                if (res1.get() == btn_réessayer) {
                                    alert.close();
                                }
                                if (res1.get() == btn_annuler) {
                                    dialog.close();
                                    alert.close();
                                }                                
                                } catch (IOException | AlreadyBoundException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            });
                            JFXButton button = new JFXButton("Terminer " + b.getText());
                            button.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                                dialog.close();
                            });
                            content.setActions(button);
                            dialog.setOverlayClose(false);
                            dialog.show();
                            dialog.setOnDialogOpened((evt) -> {

                                pn_li.setDisable(true);
                                pn_us.setDisable(true);
                            });
                            dialog.setOnDialogClosed((evt) -> {
                                pn_li.setDisable(false);
                                pn_us.setDisable(false);

                            });
                            folder.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                                try {
                                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(urep));
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    });
                    li_se.getItems().add(b);
                }
                if (!li_se.isExpanded()) {
                    li_se.setExpanded(true);
                    li_se.depthProperty().set(1);
                } 
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }                                          
}
```

This is the remote method paramService :

```
@Override
    public ArrayList paramService(String service) throws RemoteException {
        ArrayList par = null;
        try {
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/Cyberwind", "cloud", "");
            Statement sta = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT `email`, `ip`, `port` FROM `connexion` WHERE `service` = '" + service + "' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
            res.next();
            Participant_MethodsPAIR S = (Participant_MethodsPAIR) Naming.lookup("rmi://" + res.getString("ip") + ":" + res.getInt("port") + "/" + res.getString("email"));
            P = S.peer();
            par = P.getServiceParameterType(service);
            res.close();
        } catch (SQLException | NotBoundException | MalformedURLException ex) {                Logger.getLogger(Cloud_ServeurIMPL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return par;
    }
```

How to remove this RemoteException ?

Comment: No Idea what your `paramService` method does, but it does not seem to properly connect to the host for some reason. My guess is that either all connections with the parameters you provide fail or that you don't release resources associated with old connections and your server refuses multiple connections.

Comment: I figured that the port was wrong. Please take a look at my last question.